# You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'sales'

Tags: c#, mysql, oledb

Hello I have a database that looks like this:
http://up414.siz.co.il/up1/tzjdwwoio5jm.png

[image]

Now I get such an error, even though be related for Sale:

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required
>   in table 'sales'.

The code look like that:

```
private void saleStockWithProviderBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saleStockTableAdapter.Update(this.databasetDataSet.saleStock);
}
```

What's the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you're violating a foreign key constraint; your table requires a corresponding record in the sales table.

Comment: Okay, but how do I solve this ?
That's what I Updating:

databasetDataSet.saleStockRow rows = databasetDataSet.saleStock.NewsaleStockRow();
            rows.itemCode = item_codeTextBox.Text;
            rows.saleNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sale_numberTextBox.Text);
            rows.quantity = quantityTextBox.Text;
            databasetDataSet.saleStock.Rows.Add(rows);

Comment: @user3571514 you need to post your actual code (and the SQL CREATE statements for the tables in question, not just an image) in your question. Without knowing (1) your table structure and (2) the code you're using, it's impossible to give more detail.